# How to work on/access a dataframe inside a dict in python?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have 42 dataframes in a dict.
I need to work on the dataframes (outlier removal) by way of upper limit and lower limit removal.
How do I go about it when the dataframe is inside a dict?

```
for i in lst_cont:
  sigma = np.std(df[i])
  Upper_Limit = np.mean(df[i])+3*sigma
  Lower_Limit = np.mean(df[i])-3*sigma
  df2= df[(df[i]<Upper_Limit) & (df[i]>Lower_Limit)]
```

But how do I use this when the dataframes are inside a dict?

I was able to do up to this where df001 is the dict. The lst_cont is the list of all column names.

```
df002 = dict
for i in range(1,41):
  for y in lst_cont:
    sigma = dict[i][y].std()
    Upper_Limit = dict[i][y].mean()+3*sigma
    Upper_Limit = dict[i][y].mean()-3*sigma
    df002[i] = ?????????????
```

The dataframes are two columns each and I need to remove the outliers based on the values of the second column.

Edit (Update): After trying a few more times, I got till here now:

```
for i in range(1,41,1):
  df1 = dict[i]
  for x in lst_cont:
    sigma = np.std(df1[x])
    Upper_Limit = np.mean(df[x])+3*sigma
    Lower_Limit = np.mean(df[x])-3*sigma
    df002[i] = df1[(df1[x]<Upper_Limit) & (df1[x]>Lower_Limit)]
    sns.boxplot(x = df002[i][x])
    plt.savefig(str(x)+".png")
    plt.close()
```

However, I am still getting an error when the loop tries to run the second time.

Comment: What is "lst_cont"? What keys does the dictionary have?

Comment: What went wrong with your attempts? For example: `for k,df in df002.items():#do stuff`

Comment: Putting a dataframe in a dict doesn't change how you work on it.

Comment: `df002 = dict` should be `df002 = dict()` or `df002 = {}`

Comment: What is `dict[i][y]` supposed to mean? `dict` is a built-in class, not a list or dictionary.

Comment: lst_cont is a list of the column names I made from the dataframes (original csv) by df.columns. 


dict is just a variable I am using to show here (I am sorry, I didn't know it was a built in class) 


dict[i][y] is the "dictionary [ key ] [ column name ]" where "dict [i]" are all dataframes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it by using a for loop

```
for i in range(1,41,1):
  for x in lst_cont:
    df1 = df001[i]
    if x == df1.columns[1]:
      sigma = np.std(df1[x])
      Upper_Limit = np.mean(df[x])+3*sigma
      Lower_Limit = np.mean(df[x])-3*sigma
      df002[i] = df1[(df1[x]<Upper_Limit) & (df1[x]>Lower_Limit)]
      sns.boxplot(x = df002[i][x])
      plt.savefig(str(x)+".png")
      plt.close()
    else:
      continue
```